# How do I use Privoxy to replace images in the browsed pages?

Tags: proxy, privoxy

I am going to try [upside-down-ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) using `privoxy` on my proxy server.

My question is, how do I implement this on `privoxy`? My goal is to replace all ads with an image of my choice.